# Python API Output into 1st Normalized Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api

I have data that looks like this, coming out of an API:

```
    {
      "Customers": [
        {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "middle_initial": null,
          "phone_numbers": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "primary": false,
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "primary": true,
     
            }
    
          ]
}
```

How can I output the data so that it looks like this, using Python:

```
first_name     last_name     middle_initial     phone_number_id     phone_number_primary
john           doe           null               1                   false
john           doe           null               2                   true
```

Comment: the json isn't valid. Can you update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import json, requests

#from file
with open('myJson.json') as data_file:    
    d = json.load(data_file) 

#from API
d = requests.get(url).json()
```

---

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d['Customers'], 
                      'phone_numbers', 
                       ['first_name','last_name','middle_initial'],
                       record_prefix='phone_numbers_')
print (df)

  phone_numbers_id  phone_numbers_primary first_name last_name middle_initial
0                1                  False       John       Doe           None
1                2                   True       John       Doe           None
```

Comment: why the "j" before ['Customers'] on the first line? What does that do?

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles - Answer was edited.